# How can I filter a nested object with an array of values using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, lodash

I have the following data:

```
var jobs = [
{
 job_type: "Part Time",
 latitude: 49.545068,
 longitude: 0.760518,
 title: "reiciendis",
 industry: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "development" },
  { 
    id: 2,
    name: "design"
  }
 ]},
{
 job_type: "Full Time",
 latitude: 51.545068,
 longitude: 0.460518,
 title: "auteas",
 industry: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "development" },
  { 
    id: 2,
    name: "testing"
  }
 ]
```

and I'd like to try and filter the results based on a users search parameters, namely the choice of industries for a job search, which populate an array:

```
var jobchoices = ["testing", "design"];
```

my lodash filter so far looks like this:

```
var self = this

return _.filter(this.jobs, function(item) {
    return _.filter(item.industry, function(obj) {
        return _.some(self.jobchoices, obj.name);
    });
});
```

but it returns true for all jobs. This is my first time using lodash. What am I doing wrong? Secondly, could I continue chaining in this fashion to filter by another user choice, say by job type?

Comment: Aren't `development`, `testing` and `design` supposed to be strings?

Comment: You're right. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use _.filter for the main array you are trying to retrieve as the end result and then use _.chain with _.map and _.intersection to filter the internal the objects array.

Something like the code bellow should suffice, although it is not pretty.

```
var self = this;

_.filter(jobs, function(job) { 

  return _.chain(job.industry)
    .map('name')
    .intersection(self.jobchoices)
    .size()
    .gt(0)
    .value() 
})
```

(Tested only with latest lodash - v4.16.4)

Answer (score 1):

It *should* return true for all jobs, because both jobs in your example data `jobs` have matching `industry` items. If you change your `jobchoices` array to have an item (or multiple items) that only match one of your `jobs`, that could look something like this (vanilla JS):

```
var matches = jobs.filter(function(job) {
  return job.industry.some(function(industry) {
    return jobchoices.indexOf(industry.name) > -1;
  });
});
```

Or the ES6 equivalent:

```
let matches = jobs.filter(({industry} => industry.some(({name}) => jobchoices.includes(name)));
```

As to where you are going wrong, your top-level `_.filter` is returning another `_.filter` (which will return an array - *and is truthy* - therefore all items will be returned). You should be able to modify your original code return whether the inner `_.filter` call's length is `> 0` to remedy:

```
return _.filter(this.jobs, function(item) {
    var matchingIndustries = _.filter(item.industry, function(obj) {
        return _.some(self.jobchoices, obj.name);
    });
    return matchingIndustries.length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have clarified that the jobs array is a sample, there are other entries for jobs with different industries.